# Tutorial on Complex Networks

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning

Can anyone advise mea nice and short tutorial about Complex Networks? I'm reading "Networks: An Introduction" from Mark Newman, and is a bit tedious... Thanks
PS: There isn't a tag "complex networks" or tutorial...

Answer (score 6):

Would this be of any help perhaps? *Random graphs and complex networks, Volume I*, by Remco Van der Hofstad (328 pages), PDF available [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/NotesRGCN.pdf).

Comment: It seems so although appear to be a bit "too much mathematical" :p. I'll have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also, Barabasi's  [preprint](http://barabasilab.neu.edu/networksciencebook/downlPDF.html) might be helpful.